# Where can I ask "How do I get my first job at a freelancing site?"

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, site-recommendation

> "I am new to freelancing websites.The problem is I have zero rating and I can't get any projects even if I bid the lowest amount.This in turn prevents me from getting any rating which prevents me from getting any new projects.I am stuck in this cycle."

I don't know where to post this question. Do I post it in productivity, the workplace, or somewhere else? Where can I post this question so it doesn't get thumbed down and closed?

Comment: In danger of being o/t here, but to answer the question: create a website that showcases your relevant work you've done outside freelancing, such as fully-employed work and side projects.

Answer (score 5):

A [SE site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/37227/freelancing) for Freelancing is in the process. You can *Commit* to it so that it can soon reach its *beta* stage.

Comment: I have committed to this site.So I have to wait till it gets public to ask this question ?

Comment: This site will first reach its private beta stage. In this stage you can ask your question.